# \closedcycle Package pgf Warning: No path specified that can be filled on input

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am sorry if it is a silly question or problem. In the following plot, I am getting a warning. I know it has to do something with the coordinates but can't solve it for sure. If anyone can guide me in the right direction, it would be really helpful. Thank you a lot.

> Package pgf Warning: No path specified that can be filled on input
> line 55.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\title{StackExchange}
\author{M. Tahasanul Ibrahim}
\date{January 2022}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                [
                    % ybar,
                    % xmin=-1,xmax=10,
                    % ymin=0,ymax=18,
                    % xlabel={Data Value},
                    % ylabel={Occurrence/Frequency}]
                    xlabel= {Data Value}, 
                    ylabel= {Occurrence/Frequency},
                    enlarge x limits=0.1,
                    legend style={
                            at={(0.5,-0.15)},               
                            anchor=north,legend columns=-1
                    },
                    width=12.8cm,
                    height=8cm,
                    point meta={x*100},
                    symbolic x coords={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
                    grid=both,
                    grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
                    major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
                    % axis lines=middle,
                    minor tick num=5,
                    nodes near coords={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}$},
                ]
            \addplot+ [color=black, bottom color=green, top color=red] coordinates
                {
                    (0,1)
                    (1,5) 
                    (2,7) 
                    (3,12) 
                    (4,15)
                    (5,9) 
                    (6,7) 
                    (7,3) 
                    (8,0)
                    (9,1) 
                } \closedcycle;
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Area chart representing statistical data}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}`

Comment: Tried that but the warning still exists

Comment: For me it works. Try with commenting it out

Comment: @Roland, just to be sure: You don't get the **warning** by either commenting `compat` or downgrading the value to `1.17`? Or do you mean that you get the expected resulting image?

Comment: I can confirm with PGFPlots v1.18.1 and TikZ v3.1.9a that I (also) get the warning, irrespective of the `compat` level, but the resulting image is as expected.

Comment: @Stefan Pinnow Oh my bad I also still got the warning in the log file.

Comment: Yes the resulting image is as expected but the warning is there regardless of which version I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2777074/samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz) who helped me solve this issue. Here is what samcarter did and said.

These warnings arise because you are not only filling this path, you are also drawing the markers and the label markers in the same step.

If you decompose this into two separate steps, you can avoid the warnings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\title{StackExchange}
\author{M. Tahasanul Ibrahim}
\date{January 2022}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                [
                    % ybar,
                    % xmin=-1,xmax=10,
                    % ymin=0,ymax=18,
                    % xlabel={Data Value},
                    % ylabel={Occurrence/Frequency}]
                    xlabel= {Data Value}, 
                    ylabel= {Occurrence/Frequency},
                    enlarge x limits=0.1,
                    legend style={
                            at={(0.5,-0.15)},               
                            anchor=north,legend columns=-1
                    },
                    width=12.8cm,
                    height=8cm,
                    point meta={x*100},
                    symbolic x coords={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
                    grid=both,
                    grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
                    major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
                    % axis lines=middle,
                    minor tick num=5,
%                    nodes near coords={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}$},
                ]
            \addplot [color=black, bottom color=green, top color=red] coordinates
                {
                    (0,1)
                    (1,5) 
                    (2,7) 
                    (3,12) 
                    (4,15)
                    (5,9) 
                    (6,7) 
                    (7,3) 
                    (8,0)
                    (9,1) 
                } \closedcycle;
                
            \addplot+[black,mark=*,nodes near coords={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}$},] coordinates
                {
                    (0,1)
                    (1,5) 
                    (2,7) 
                    (3,12) 
                    (4,15)
                    (5,9) 
                    (6,7) 
                    (7,3) 
                    (8,0)
                    (9,1) 
                };                
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Area chart representing statistical data}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]